# Converting the regular expression to a grammar

Tags: regex, grammar, left-recursion

I have the following regular expression:

```
(12)*[34]+(5[67])*
```

How can I convert the expression to a grammar that is left recursive?

I came up with this. I did not follow any methods or anything...

```
G --> GAB34C
A --> A12 | epsilon
B --> B34 | epsilon
C --> C56 | C57 | epsilon
```

Comment: Please, don't add text as images. Copy the text into the question.

Comment: B seems wrong if `[`...`]` has the normal regex meaning

Comment: Thats true, so it should be like this

G --> GAB34C
A --> A12 | epsilon
B --> B3|B4 | epsilon
C --> C56 | C57 | epsilon

Otherwise, is the grammar correct??

Answer (score 2):

As commented, 34 is not a correct rule as 3 and 4 are *alternates*. This not only affects the second rule, but also the first.

Not a problem, but `C56 | C57` can be written as `C5(6|7)`

So:

```
G → A(3|4)BC
A → A12 | ε
B → B(3|4) | ε
C → C5(6|7) | ε
```

If G must also employ left recursion itself, then put the C-recursion inside G (eliminate C):

```
G → G5(6|7) | A(3|4)B
A → A12 | ε
B → B(3|4) | ε
```

And maybe it is more elegant to keep `(3|4)` in the definition of B:

```
G → G5(6|7) | AB
A → A12 | ε
B → B(3|4) | (3|4)
```

#### Script

Here is an implementation with generators in JavaScript. It produces some random strings in the grammar:

```js
const coin = () => Math.random() < 0.5;

function* G() {
    if (coin()) {
        yield* G();
        yield 5;
        yield coin() ? 6 : 7;
    } else {
        yield* A();
        yield* B();
    }
}

function* A() {
    if (coin()) {
        yield* A();
        yield 1;
        yield 2;
    }
}

function* B() {
    if (coin()) {
        yield* B();
        yield coin() ? 3 : 4;
    } else {
        yield coin() ? 3 : 4;
    }
}

// Produce some random strings
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) console.log(...G());
```

Comment: If am not wrong, G never terminates? So should it be like this then?

G → GA(3|4)BC|3|4
A → A12 | ε
B → B(3|4) | ε
C → C5(6|7) | ε

Comment: @kiwi, you're right; It looks like G should not have a recursive G in its definition. Even `G→GA(3|4)BC|3|4` is problematic as after C there should never follow a 1,2,3 or 4.

Comment: If a do like this it should be correct? And this is still left recursive even though there is no recursion in G?

G → A(3|4)BC 
A → A12 | ε 
B → B(3|4) | ε 
C → C5(6|7) | ε

Comment: I think this is not right...

G → G12 | BC
B → B(3|4) | (3|4)
C → C5(6|7) | ε

Because G12 can only stop when we use BC infront of G12. Hence we can get 312

Comment: Right, I mistakenly had chosen A  as suffix after the recurrent G. Should be C. See update.